# Rodapé é metade traduzido e metade não

Tags: bug, status-intencional

Não tenho certeza se consiste em um bug ou se era pra ser assim mesmo, mas como não achei postado aqui ainda, aqui vai:

A tem uma parte do rodapé não traduzida, logo após as palavras azuis:

[image: Rodapé]

Comment: This will not be translated, as these are the actual names of the sites, in the same way that the Stack Exchange will not get translated.

Comment: @Oded I think the category titles should be translated anyway. `Technology -> Tecnologia`, `Life / Arts -> Vida / Artes`, and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

acho que deveriam estar traduzidos os títulos das listas e a ação de cada uma:

- ## Títulos

  #### Technology

  > Tecnologia

  #### Life / Arts

  > Vida / artes

  #### Culture / Recreation

  > Cultura / Lazer

  #### Science

  > Ciência

  #### Other

  > Outros
- ## Ação

  #### more (x)

  > mais (x)

---

Tudo o resto ou são nomes, cujos mesmos nunca são traduzidos, ou é uma informação de *copyright* que na sua essência não tem grande tradução dado serem *regra geral* terminologias comummente conhecidas que não carecem tradução ou a serem traduzidas iriam ficar num formato um pouco estranho para muitos de nós.

Ainda assim, a traduzir a informação de copyright, poderiamos ter:

#### site design / logo © 2014 stack exchange inc; user contributions licensed under cc by-sa 3.0 with attribution required

> design do site / logótipo © 2014 stack exchange inc; contribuições dos utilizadores licenciadas sobre cc by-sa 3.0 com atribuição obrigatória